# Angular Material align table expandable row content with one of row columns

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material 13 to create a table with expandable rows. The example from the Angular Material page works fine:
https://v13.material.angular.io/components/table/examples

I want to display some key - value pairs in the row expansion and I'm trying to do so right now using a Bootstrap table, but I can't seem to make the content align with a particular column of the `mat-table`:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="listData" class="full-width-table" multiTemplateDataRows>
        <!-- Download And View Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="download">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <button type="button" class="btn rounded-pill-small me-1" (click)="onSelect(row); $event.stopPropagation();">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn rounded-pill-small me-1" (click)="download(row); $event.stopPropagation()">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-download"></i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Date Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row?.date | date: 'MMM d, yyyy HH:mm'}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Number Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row?.number}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        
        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row?.name}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Total -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="totalFinal">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Total</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{(row?.totalFinal || '0')}} {{row?.currency}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
            <div class="example-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="row == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
              <div class="example-element-description">
                <table class="table">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Key 1</th>
                      <td>row.value1</td>
                      <th>Key 2</th>
                      <td>row.value2</td>
                      <th>Key 3</th>
                      <td>row.value3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Key 4</th>
                      <td>row.value4</td>
                      <th>Key 5</th>
                      <td>row.value5</td>
                      <th>Key 6</th>
                      <td>row.value6</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Actions Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <div class="float-end">
              <button mat-icon-button (click)="onEdit(row); $event.stopPropagation()">
                <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
              </button>
              <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="onDelete(row); $event.stopPropagation()">
                <mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon>
              </button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="loading">
          <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
            Loading data...
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="noData">
          <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
            No data.
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" class="example-element-row"
          [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === row"
          (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === row ? null : row">
        </tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
        <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['loading']" [ngClass]="{'hide':listData!=null}" class="text-center"></tr>
        <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']"
          [ngClass]="{'hide':!(listData!=null && listData.data.length==0)}" class="text-center"></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
.full-width-table {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Expand row */
  tr.example-detail-row {
    height: 0;
  }
  
  tr.example-element-row:not(.example-expanded-row):hover {
    background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  }
  
  tr.example-element-row:not(.example-expanded-row):active {
    background: #efefef;
  }
  
  .example-element-row td {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
  }
  
  .example-element-detail {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .example-element-description {
    padding: 16px;
  }
```

How do I make the Key 1 - Value 1 and Key 4 - Value 4 column be aligned with the second column of the `mat-table` (i.e the `date` column), Key 2 - Value 2 and Key 5 - Value 5 column be aligned with another column and so on?